# execute immediate ora-01704 string literal too long

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following code

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL name_package.name_procedure('string literal too long...')';
END;
```

when I run it I get the following error:

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
ORA-06512: line 2
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

I have tried with a variable clob but the error persists, some idea of how to solve this issue, i am using oracle 11g

Comment: Why are you calling the procedure inside of an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? If there isn't a compelling reason, then the obvious choice would be to just call the procedure directly.

Comment: I have a Java class that invokes procedures, these procedures return html structures

public String getHtmlORACLE(String storeprocedure) throws Exception {
...
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
.....
sql.append("{call package_print.name_procedure001('"+buffer+"',?)}");
cs = conn.prepareCall(sql.toString());
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CLOB);
cs.executeUpdate();
html = cs.getString(1);
...

the "buffer" variable contains the name of the other package and its procedure.
when the query is made in the database the problem is presented

Answer (score 1):

Use a bind variable:

```
DECLARE
  str CLOB := EMPTY_CLOB();
BEGIN
  -- Make a long (random) string:
  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    str := str || DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( 'a', 4000 );
  END;

  -- Pass it into the dynamic SQL:
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CALL name_package.name_procedure( :1 )' USING str;

  -- Or just call the procedure without dynamic SQL:
  name_package.name_procedure( str );
END;
```

Comment: I have a Java class that invokes procedures, these procedures return html structures

public String getHtmlORACLE(String storeprocedure) throws Exception {
...
...
buffer.append(param1);
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(); 
sql.append("{call package_print.name_procedure001('"+buffer+"',?)}");
cs = conn.prepareCall(sql.toString());
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CLOB);
cs.executeUpdate();
html = cs.getString(1);
...

the "buffer" variable contains the name of the other package and its procedure.
when the query is made in the database the problem is presented

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you are trying to accomplish.  Within a PL/SQL block you would need only reference name_package.name_procedure('string').  Assuming name_procedure is defined in the specification of name_package.

```
BEGIN
    name_package.name_procedure('string');
END;
```

CLOB variable would work in place of 'string' but only if that parameter is defined as CLOB and not as VARCHAR2.

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE requires a string.  Quotes within a quoted string need to be presented twice.

Comment: I have a Java class that invokes procedures, these procedures return html structures public String getHtmlORACLE(String storeprocedure) throws Exception { ... StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); ..... sql.append("{call package_print.name_procedure001('"+buffer+"',?)}"); cs = conn.prepareCall(sql.toString()); cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.CLOB); cs.executeUpdate(); html = cs.getString(1); ... the "buffer" variable contains the name of the other package and its procedure. when the query is made in the database the problem is presented

Comment: You tagged this as Oracle and PLSQL.  Java was not mentioned.  The same principles should apply though.  PL/SQL block might work when called from java but the string you pass would still need to have all single-quotes presented as doubled single_quotes.